# How to call function in UserControl every 2 minutes in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, user-interface

So i created UserControl with dataGridView, actually how I will this object is less important, but let's say i have alredy DataSource and I want to refresh dataGridView with these values.

on example i have function **fillDataGridView()** and I want it to call every 2 minutes

I think that I could do this with Thread class, but w/o any success yet

How do you deal with UI refresh?

I know that this looks like "yet another guy with UI update problem", but from what I saw I really can't the easiest way to do it

```
public partial class Alertbox : UserControl
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public Alertbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Update);

        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Update(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        BT_AddTrigger.Text += "test"; // append to button text
    }
}
```

It shout's that

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'BT_AddTrigger'
>   accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: To prevent cross threading, use: `BT_AddTrigger.Invoke(new Action<string>(UpdateButtonText), new object[] {text});` like here: https://gist.github.com/PopovMP/8f747dbd6948eccc69ad. However, better option is to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` since you are in a UserControl.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use timer class in this way

```
            System.Timers.Timer testTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            testTimer.Enabled = true;
            //testTimer.Interval = 3600000; //1 hour timer
            testTimer.Interval = 100000;// Execute timer every // five seconds
            testTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(FillGrid);
```

Comment: There several issues here: 1. Cross-threading call to winforms control, 2. you must set `testTimer.AutoReset = true`, 3. `testTimer.Interval = 100000;` is 100 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of System.Timer.Timer.

You're getting the `Cross Thread Operation Not Valid` error because System.Timer.Timer runs on a different thread, and you can't invoke an operation on a Winforms thread from another thread without calling [Control.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx).

System.Windows.Forms.Timer will use the same thread as the UI, and you'll avoid these problems.

Comment: Here is the detailed comparison of the different timer classes in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the handy Timer classes in .Net to trigger every 2 min.

Here is an example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Added a link to one example

Comment: Yes I am, I also added exception error in main post

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Windows.Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public Alertbox()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new Timer {Interval = 2*60*1000};
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BT_AddTrigger.Text += "test";
}
```